# Why does hitTestObject detect the collision late?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, collision

I'm making this quick pong game and using hitTestObject to check for the collision. Shouldn't be a problem, since everything is rectangle anyway. Each ball in the vector is checking to see if it's colliding with the paddle every frame. Why does each ball not trigger the collision until it gets about half way through it? I can't call a function more frequently than enter_frame does, or can I? I just seems like it's not updating fast enough or something.

```
if (ball[i].hitTestObject(paddle)){

     // Flip
     ball[i] *= -1;
}
```

Quick pic of it:

[image]

Comment: How are you drawing the ball? and how does that compare to the borders?

Comment: It's a movie clip and has a class that extends Sprite since I don't need full movie clip functionality. The ball the only thing in the movie clip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume it's because that's where the ball is when you run the hit test, as it's only checking momentary locations instead of a smooth line of movement. In other words, if on one frame the edge of the ball is 5px away from the paddle, the hit test will be false. If the ball then moves 8px on the next frame, the hit test will be true, but the ball edge will be 3px inside the paddle.

When I have a simple flat edge like this to test, I tend to do something along these lines (given a ball with `speedY` and `radius` variables, and `paddle.y` == the leading edge of the paddle):

```
if (ball.y + ball.radius > paddle.y) {
    // Mirror the ball's speed
    ball.speedY *= -1;

    // Mirror the ball's location as if it had bounced on the edge
    // by moving it back by the same distance it went past.
    ball.y -= (ball.y + ball.radius - paddle.y) * 2;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same, but I've tried this, and other variations of it, and it still has the same problem. What you say makes sense though. It just keeps going about half way through. Ugh. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you moving your balls before or after you check for collisions?

Comment: You need to preemptively check for your collisions. Instead of moving the ball and then checking for a collision (which by then is too late as the ball is potentially already hitting/overlapping in the object), you need to project where the ball will be and check for collisions against that, before the ball is already hitting/overlapping the object. David's bit of code shows this.

Comment: I see no projecting of where the ball is going to be in David's code. I see a simple resetting of the ball to the edge of the stage if it's gone past it. I've been looking at tracking the difference in time between frames but have gotten strange results at best. David's mention of smooth line movement sparked that idea, but balls start randomly disappearing off the stage upon bouncing sometimes.

Comment: I had the balls moving on their own update loops (based on enter_frame, of course), but I figured it would be best to keep everything on the main loop so I created a public function that can be called to move the balls from the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is update the ball's position so that it sits against the edge of the paddle once there is a collision.

The issues you're having at the moment is that if you ball is travelling at 12 pixels per frame and is 2 pixels away from the bat, the ball will bypass the edge of the bat by 10 pixels the next frame and give you the visual result you're seeing.

```
if( /* your hit detection */ )
{
    // Move the ball so that it's sitting against the paddle here.
    //
}
```